# Datagrid Column Selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to check one column of `DataGridView` to see whether if it is 0 or 1. I also want it to print the number of 0 or 1 and write it to the `TextBox`. I tried this code but I it gives an error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            DataGridViewRow rw = new DataGridViewRow();
            if (Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["values4"].Value) == 0)
            {


                rw.HeaderCell.Value = rw.Index + 1;
                txtBasarili.Text = rw.HeaderCell.Value.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: what error you get? what you want write in textbox?

Comment: Why [Application.DoEvents()](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/) ? Also why are you creating new instances of `DataGridViewRow`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Grid_Click Event Write then

```
 private void grdform1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {  
     If(e.ColumnIndex==0 ||e.ColumnIndex==1)
      {
       txtshowcolunm.text=e.ColumnIndex;
          }
        else
        {
      txtshowcolunm.text=e.ColumnIndex;
    }
       }
```